# Finding $x$ and $y$ such that $\frac {(a^x)^2}{b^{5-x}} \cdot \frac {b^{y-4}}{a^y} = a^2 b^4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find the value of $x$ and the value of $y$.
> $$\frac {(a^x)^2}{b^{5-x}} \cdot \frac {b^{y-4}}{a^y} = a^2 b^4$$

I am not sure how to multiply these so I could equate the exponent $a$ to $2$ and $b$ to $4$.

Comment: The left-hand side will give you $a^{2x-y}$. Then do as you said. You will end up with a system of equations to solve.

Comment: @DavidP is it $2x-y$ because the denominator always subtracts the numerator or is there another reason it is not $y - 2x$

Comment: $a^m/a^n=a^{m-n}$. Pull out the laws of exponents when working on these if you need to.

Comment: Understood, thanks.

Comment: @DavidP im getting the answer $x = 15,  y = 28$ after solving $2x-y=2, and -x+y=13$ simultaneously; which is incorrect.

Comment: $y-4-(5-x) = x+y-9$

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach.

$$\frac{a^{2x}b^{y-4}}{a^yb^{5-x}}=a^xb^y$$

$$a^{2x-y}b^{y+x-9}=a^xb^y$$

You then end up with the system of equations
$$\begin{array}{c}
2x-y \\
y+x=13 \\
\end{array}
$$

This solves out to x=5, y=8. Hope this helped!